# Getting the title of post

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get the title of a post using simple_html_dom the html roots can be seen below the part I am trying to get is titled *This Is Our Title*.

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="section">
    <div id="sectionleft">
      <p>
        Latest News
      </p>
      <ul class="cont news">
        <li>
          <div style="padding: 1px;">
            <a href="http://www.example.com">
              <img src="http://www.example.com/our-image.png" width="128" height="96" alt="">
            </a>
          </div>
          <a href="http://www.example.com" class="name">
            This is our title 
            </a>
          <i class="info">added: Dec 16, 2015</i>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently I have this

```
$page = (isset($_GET['p'])&&$_GET['p']!=0) ? (int) $_GET['p'] : '';

$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/'.$page);

foreach($html->find('div#section ul.cont li div a') as $element)
{
    print '<br><br>';
    echo $url = 'http://www.example.com/'.$element->href;

    $html2 = file_get_html($url);

    print '<br>';

    $image = $html2->find('meta[property=og:image]',0);
    print $image = $image->content;

    print '<br>';

    $title = $html2->find('#sectionleft ul.cont news li a.name',0);
    print $title = $title->plaintext;

    print '<br>';
}
```

The issue is here `$title = $html2->find('#sectionleft ul.cont news li a.name',0);` I assume I am using the wrong selector but I am literally not sure what I am doing wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ul.cont news` means "find `<news>` elements that are a child of `ul.cont`".

You actually want:

```
#sectionleft ul.cont.news li a.name
```

EDIT: For some reason, it seems `simple_html_dom` doesn't like `ul.cont.news` even though it's a valid CSS selector.

You can try

```
#sectionleft ul[class="cont news"] li a.name
```

which should work **as long as** the classes are in *that* order.

Comment: @Open I think you forgot the div: `$title = $html2->find('div#sectionleft ul.cont\.news li a.name',0);`

Comment: @dstudeba: That shouldn't matter.  `sectionleft` is an ID; it's unique throughout the whole page.

Comment: @dstudeba doesn't work either, just displays an empty space instead of showing the title we're going after.

Comment: @RocketHazmat thanks, I should go back to beautifulSoup

Comment: When I change the code from the snippet in OP to what you said here `$title = $html2->find('div#sectionleft ul.cont.news li a.name',0);` nothing changes at all, but upon looking further into it, it should..

Comment: @Open: I have no idea why, but it seems simple_html_dom doesn't like `ul.cont.news`.  EDIT: I found this: http://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/bugs/149/ and http://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/bugs/119/.  Looks like this is an unfixed issue in the library.

Comment: @RocketHazmat is there any loop around to this? If I remove the `.cont.news` it will just pull random content throughout the page which is inside of an `a` tag.

Comment: @Open: I added another thing to the answer you can try.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Didn't work also, QQ well at least I know that it's not just me having this issue or something similar.

Comment: @Open: It seems to work for me with `ul[class="cont news"]`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat can you edit with the `$title` string you're using?

Comment: @Open: I did.  The line in the answer seems to work.  See: http://ideone.com/v5jLHh (You'll need to scroll all the way to the bottom, I had to include the entire simple_html_dom file in the example)

Comment: thanks, this fixed it @RocketHazmat I don't know why I was having so much trouble with this!

Comment: @Open: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

If this seems a little *hacky*, forgive me, but... you can always employ PHP to run a quick `.js`:

```
<?php

echo '<script>';
echo 'var postTitle = document.querySelector("ul.cont.news a.name").innerHTML;';
if (!isset($_GET['posttitle'])) {
echo 'window.location.href = window.location.href + "?posttitle=" + postTitle';}
echo '</script>';

$postTitle = $_GET['posttitle'];

?>
```